# Construction of a pentagon in which an angle bisector at a certain vertex is also a perpendicular bisector of a side opposite to that vertex

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

**Construct a pentagon $ABCDE$ if  lengths of its sides are $a,b,c,d$ and $e$ ($|AB|=a,|BC|=b,...$), and the bisector of the angle at vertex $D$ is also the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.**

I know that $D\in f$, $C\in c_1=c(B,b)$ and $E\in c_2=c(A,e)$.
[image]

How do I find the exact position of point $D$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=AD=BD$. By the triangular inequality we have the constraints:
$$
|b-c|<x<b+c
\quad\text{and}\quad
|d-e|<x<d+e.
$$

For the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ to be also the bisector of $\angle CDE$ we must have $\angle ADE=\angle BDC$. By the cosine rule this implies:
$$
{d^2+x^2-e^2\over 2dx}=
{c^2+x^2-b^2\over 2cx},
$$
that is:
$$
x^2={d(c^2-b^2)-c(d^2-e^2)\over c-d}.
$$
Of course this gives a solution only if $x>a/2$ and if the above constraints are satisfied.

Example. Setting
$$
a=4,\quad
b=7,\quad
c=4,\quad
d=6,\quad
e=4
$$
we get $x=\sqrt{139}$, which is larger than $b+c$. Hence no solution exists.

Comment: Sir, I am very sorry to bother you but I just have to ask this.
In order to construct $ABCDE$ I chose the following lengths:
$a=4$,
$b=7$,
$c=4$,
$d=6$,
$e=4$.

Now $|b-c|<AD<b+c=3<AD<11$ and 
$|d-e|<AD<d+e=2<AD<10$. So I chose $|AD|$ to be 5.  I do end up with a pentagon with its sides being of required lengths and $D$ lying on line $f$, but the obtained pentagon doesn't satisfy the condition that $f$ has to also bisect $\angle EDC$. I added the picture of all this to my original post. I suppose I misunderstood your instructions. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @kaykay If you don’t understand the answer, you should not give it the green check mark.

Comment: Does this answer consider the bisector of angle $D$?

Comment: @DavidK Or maybe...just maybe.. I can give the green check mark to whomever I please? I appreciate every single answer I get even if it's not fully correct/clear to me. Besides, nothing intelligenti pauca stated is mathematically incorrect. already had a bad experience with some guy named David on here. Are all Davids on this forum nosy or it's just me having bad luck?

Comment: @kaykay You are right: I did'n notice it had to be an angle bisector. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @kaykay Instead of deleting I edited my answer, to take into account the second request.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Awesome!! Thanks for solving it in a way even us newbies can understand, means a lot

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Sir, it is my pleasure to inform you that I have successfully passed the  Construction methods in geometry course. I am extremely grateful for each and every one of your comments over the past few months. They helped me a lot and gave me hope when it was the most difficult. I often couldn't see the solution to the problem, even when it was literally trivial. You still took the time out of your day to kindly answer all of my questions. The most important thing is that I went from a total beginner to a lover of Euclidean geometry and now I see its true merits.Thank you!!❤

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_{1}$ be the projection of $E$ onto $f$, and define $C_{1}$ similarly. Because $f$ bisects $\angle CDE$, $\triangle DC_{1}C\sim\triangle DE_{1}E$.

Let $\angle CDE = 2\theta$. Then, $DE_{1} = d\cos(\theta)$ and $DC_{1} = c\cos(\theta)$. Also, $EE_{1}=d\sin(\theta)$ and $CC_{1}=c\sin(\theta)$.

Let $A_{1}$ be the projection of $A$ onto $EE_{1}$ and let $B_{1}$ be the projection of $B$ onto $CC_{1}$. We have $EA_{1} = d\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}$, so $AA_{1} = \sqrt{e^{2}-\left(d\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}}$ by the Pythagorean Theorem. Similarly, $BB_{1}=\sqrt{b^{2}-\left(c\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}}$.

Letting $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$, note that $ME_{1} = AA_{1}$ and $MC_{1} + BB_{1}$. However, we must have $ME_{1}+DE_{1} = MC_{1}+DC_{1}$. Thus:

$$d\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{e^{2}-\left(d\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}} = c\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{b^{2}-\left(c\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}}$$

This equation can be numerically solved for $\theta$ (possible analytically as well, although it may be too messy to be worth it). Then, $MD = d\cos(\theta)+\sqrt{e^{2}-\left(d\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Defining $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as the exterior angles at $A$ and $B$, and $\theta$ as the complement of the half-angle at $D$, and $a_2:=a/2$ for convenience, "all we have to do" is solve the system

$$\begin{align}
d \cos\theta &= a_2 + e \cos\alpha \tag1\\
c \cos\theta &= a_2 + b \cos\beta \tag2\\
d \sin\theta + e \sin\alpha &= c \sin\theta + b \sin\beta \tag3
\end{align}$$

The special case of $c=d$ clearly implies $b=e$ and $\alpha=\beta$, making the pentagon symmetric about the angle/perpendicular bisector, although its shape is not uniquely determined.

Otherwise ... A couple of rounds of squaring of $(3)$ will give us even powers of $\sin\alpha$ and $\sin\beta$, which we can replace with powers of $1-\cos^2\alpha$ and $1-\cos^2\beta$; substituting $\cos\alpha$ and $\cos\beta$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$, and simplifying, gives this quadratic in $\cos\theta$:

$$\begin{align}
0 &=\phantom{-}\;4\cos^2\theta\;(c - d) (d (b^2 - c^2) - c (e^2 - d^2)) \\
&\quad-4 \cos\theta\;a_2 (c - d) ((b^2 - c^2) - (e^2 - d^2))\\ 
&\quad-4 a_2^2 (c - d)^2 - (b + c - d - e) (b - c + d - e) (b + c - d + e) (b - c + d + e)
\end{align}$$

Solving gives

$$\begin{align}
\cos\theta &= \frac{a_2 (c - d) (b^2 - c^2 + d^2 - e^2)\pm \sigma}{2p (c - d)} \\[8pt]
\sigma &:= \sqrt{ q(c - d)   \left(a_2^2(c-d) + p\right)} \\[2pt]
p &:= d(b^2-c^2)-c(e^2-d^2) \\[4pt]
q &:= (b + c - d - e)(b + c - d + e)(b - c + d + e)  (b - c + d - e)
\end{align}$$

And then, from $(1)$ and $(2)$,
$$\begin{align}
\cos\alpha &= \frac{a_2(c-d)((c-d)(e^2-d^2)-p)\pm d\sigma}{2ep(c-d)} \\[4pt]
\cos\beta  &= \frac{a_2(c-d)((c-d)(b^2-c^2)-p)\pm c\sigma}{2bp(c-d)}
\end{align}$$
where the $\pm$ represents the same sign throughout.

Of course, $\sigma$ must be real for a solution to exist. Whether one or the other (or both, or neither) states of the "$\pm$" leads to an extraneous solution is left as an exercise to the reader. $\square$